# Getting Google PageRank via an API (PHP)

Tags: php, api, pagerank

I have a list of domains and would like to get the:

1. PageRank for all the domains. So just an integer, there must be an API that returns this.
2. The number of results in Google
3. The position of the word of the domainname. For example, "google.com" would be the position of the word "google". This could be position 20.

Comment: have you got any solution ???

Comment: what does "The position of the word of the domainname" mean?

Comment: there is no pagerank API but you can get toolbar PageRank using this script http://99webtools.com/php-script-to-get-pagerank.php

Comment: Question probably unanswerable nowadays, see also http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84955/how-to-find-google-pagerank-without-third-party-tools#comment103078_84955

Answer (score 41):

This will have everything you need.
https://github.com/eyecatchup/SEOstats

Amazing.

Comment: FYI, you can't follow the directions on the linked page above, you have to go directly to the github and download the source from github, and use the examples there.  The example in the code.google.com/p/seostats redirects you to a google terms of service thing.  It was fixed in the github version.

Answer (score 7):

I've published a [Pagerank API](http://api.nahklick.de/pagerank/ch.php?url=http://www.stackoverflow.com) that returns a json array, containing the checksum and the Pagerank of any URL.

I also have a bunch of [related tools](http://api.nahklick.de/seo/index.php) and a [Google code project](http://code.google.com/p/seostats/) that might interest you.

Comment: This has since been shut down.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i needed to take it off yesterday.Yesterday some bastards were firing off up to 500k requests per hour!!! And even though this was running on a high performance nginx machine with a dynamic IP restriction leading into an emtpy server response (nginx 444), those monkeys did not stopped firing their requests. And i can not accept an loading latency on my commercial websites.

I will re-open the API asap, but on an extra server. You will find the updates on that at the SEOstats project page: http://code.google.com/p/seostats/

Comment: No need to apologise, @Seo. Those are some nice looking tools. I edited your post so I could undo my down vote, and added a few more links to make it easier for others to find what you've built. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

1. There isn't an API.  However, there are ways to do it, all potentially problematic.  If you were willing to use Python, I recently discovered a [script](http://www.halotis.com/2009/08/02/google-page-range-python-script/) to do it.
2. Google used to have a SOAP API, but no longer.  Some people scrape the results.  You can try to get it from the AJAX API, but there's not a public API for this.
3. I don't understand you question here.  Could you clarify and I'll update my answer?

Comment: Thanks Marcc.

3. This will strip the TLD and return the position of the domainname. For example: domainword.com will be "domainword", there should be a search for the word and the position in Google should be returned.

Comment: www.halotis.com also has a script which will return the SERP (Search Engine Result Placement) for keywords.  Google doesn't make available any tool to do what you need, but there are scripts out there to do it.

Comment: SERP means Search Engine Result Page(s), he wants to know the SERP Ranking of any given domain for any given search query.

Comment: You know, I sat there with Placement or Page.  Thinking, which one is it?  Next time, I'll open a tab and google it...  It's not hard to get the SERP for a keyword from google, but unless you already have a SOAP API key, you'll probably be scraping to get it.

Comment: 1. tried that. I had to fix two syntax errors and still did not work for me as google changed the policy (`Your client does not have permission to get URL..`)

Answer (score 1):

Try this guy: http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/PageRank/

although written in perl, you can issue a call to your OS from PHP to run this, then further process the output.  Make sure to put http:// at the beginning your your query, and not hit the google server more often than once per second, and sanitize (urlencode) the user input if users will be using this.