# How do I get the pagerank of a website programmatically?

Tags: api, seo

Is there any API that gives me the page rank of a website programmatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Google PageRank via an API (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344917/getting-google-pagerank-via-an-api-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you mean with pagerank the green bar on top of the google toolbar, just make a get request to

http://toolbarqueries.google.at/tbr?features=Rank&sourceid=navclient-ff&client=navclient-auto-ff&googleip=O;173.194.35.104;539&iqrn=O6uB&querytime=5X&orig=0gjuj&swwk=-1&ch=805513e7f&q=info:https://stackoverflow.com/

the last figure is the google toolbar pagerank figure (also known as green bar pagerank)

but it is not the real google pagerank (which isn't a figure beteween 0 and 10) and it is not even an estimate of the value of your page, it is just a figure google communicates to webmasters to turn on the "submit data to us" option of the toolbar. my recommendation is: just ignore it.

Comment: Any clue how that works? I tried to change the URL but I got an error

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to dig up an old question, but I had this same problem, and found a way to solve it.

The "&ch=" part is a checksum of the domain/page you are trying to find the "fake PR" for.

Use the code from here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20038/Request-Google-s-Page-rank-Programmatically

Replace the original URL with the URL provided by Franz (http://toolbarqueries.google.at/tbr?features=Rank&sourceid=navclient-ff&client=navclient-auto-ff&googleip=O;173.194.35.104;539&iqrn=O6uB&querytime=5X&orig=0gjuj&swwk=-1&ch=805513e7f&q=info:http://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy to use http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/PageRank/