# Get Bing's PageRank and Yahoo's PageRank of a website using C# or VB.Net

Tags: c#, yahoo, bing, bing-api, pagerank

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260474/how-do-i-get-the-pagerank-of-a-website-programmatically) and [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20038/Request-Google-s-Page-rank-Programmatically), I have been able to get the Google PageRank of a website using C#. I would also like to get the PageRank for Bing and Yahoo. For Bing, the only link that I could find is [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251056.aspx). Not sure, if there are any other ways of doing so.

Any ideas or solutions?

Comment: I am not asking to write any code but to point me in some direction that could help me write code. I hope the question is not downvoted.

Comment: This is also off-topic here, as explained in my first comment (haven't you been member of SO for long enough to know that? I know it and have been a member only during half of your time you have been). Regarding downvotes, it seems that you don't need to worry too much about this today. Not sure about the reason, but there are quite a few questions being unfairly upvoted in the C# tag (what rarely happens). Anyway... if you don't want to be downvoted/get answers, ask what is expected; if you have still doubts about what SO is about, you should take a look at the help pages.