# Query pagerank from Google API?

Tags: php, search-engine

I have a script that calls the Google API server to return the top 8 results for any given query. However, the one piece of data that's missing is the pagerank.

I'd like to find out if its possible to add a querystring paramater to get the PR.

Here is my current query...

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&rsz=8&q=search+engine+optimization
```

And based one a bit of research, I've found that some are using the "features=Rank" parameter, however, I see no difference in the results.

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&rsz=8&features=Rank&q=search+engine+optimization
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344917/getting-google-pagerank-via-an-api-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they do not provide any APIs

However Web Ninja Google PageRank API will do somework for you

Check out there page http://josh-fowler.com/?page_id=163

Comment: +1 Thanks for the link. I suppose I'm trying to do for myself, what josh is doing for others. I need control over the API and to host the code on my server to regulate access.

Comment: mmm...well..you can ask him from his website straight away and please remember to post it here so I might learn sth. from later use :)

Answer (score 0):

Google does not generally expose PageRank publicly. The closest they've gotten in the past is displaying a number which resembles PageRank in the Google Toolbar, and it's pretty well known that the values shown in there are per-site, not per-page, and are not updated frequently.

Comment: Thanks for the info on Google toolbar. You taught me something. I was under impression the PR reading was for the specific page being viewed, not the site as a whole. I've never heard anyone say Google ranks "sites". I think the conventional wisdom is that they rank *pages*, so this is definitely interesting.

Comment: Google does (appear to) rank pages internally. The Google Toolbar is just presenting a simplified version of the actual data.