# Checking domain Page Rank from C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to get a Page Rank (PR) value of a domain from C#.

I am using the code from this site:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20038/Request-Google-s-Page-rank-Programmatically

But it doesn't work for me. All it does is return -1.

Did google turn off their API for pagerank checking?

There is surprisingly very low info about this on the net.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Google PageRank via an API (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344917/getting-google-pagerank-via-an-api-php)

Comment: there may be some unofficial way to access pagerank, but [Google has been discouraging its use](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/06/beyond-pagerank-graduating-to.html) for the last 3 years so I doubt they offer a straightforward way to access it programmatically.

Comment: So the code I linked to no longer works? It just gives me -1 all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google just changed its PR server and as a result also changed its query URL.

The old query URL is:
http://toolbarqueries.google.com/search?client=navclient-auto&features=Rank&ch=8f3b58e04&q=info:[URLHERE]

The new query URL is:
http://toolbarqueries.google.com/tbr?client=navclient-auto&features=Rank&ch=8f3b58e04&q=info:[URLHERE]  
So you can try query like this 
http://toolbarqueries.google.com/tbr?client=navclient-auto&features=Rank&ch={url ComputeHash }&q=info:{url}

It will return you response like that **Rank_1:1:9**,which can be parsed to get the page rank.