# How to check the rank of website on google?

Tags: javascript

I have made a site on .NET and I want to check the rank of my site on Google. I don't want to use any Google API or any Page Rank checker tool. Is there any way to check the rank of my site through code?.

Comment: api is code. just saying.

Comment: http://www.alexa.com/ its out there. why not use it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about SEO are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 3):

In Google's TOS it says:

> You specifically agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the
>   Services through any automated means (including use of scripts or web
>   crawlers).

if you build a query for checking something. it might work for a while. but then it will ask if you are a human.

Answer (score 1):

Try [SEOStats](https://github.com/eyecatchup/SEOstats) or http://www.halotis.com/2009/08/02/google-page-range-python-script/

Refer to [Getting Google PageRank via an API (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344917/getting-google-pagerank-via-an-api-php)

Comment: This is the way to do it, but doesn't quite fit the question requirements: "I dont want to use any google api or any page rank checker tool"

Comment: http://awordpress.net/google-pagerank-checker-php/

Comment: Huh? you don't want any checker tool but you need the pagerank, ok open the tool, go through the code and rewrite the logic in your favorite programming language.